# Forming a regular expression to a Java string

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a String, where only numbers and none, one or more percentages are allowed

so my regex would be: `[\d+%]`, you can test it [here](http://regexr.com?32lin)

for java i have to transform it,

```
public static final String regex = "[\\d+\\%]";
```

and to test it i use this function

```
public static final String regex = "[\\d+\\%]";

public boolean validate(String myString){

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(myString);

    if (!matcher.matches()) {
        return false;
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

The regular expression is not working, also if i use

```
public static final String regex = "[\\d+%]";
```

Is there any good online tool for escaping a long regular expression for java?

A more advanced question:
the % should be only allowed if a minimum of one digit is in the String, only a % shouldn't be allowed! And: numbers without a `%`  are only allowed if the number of digits is exactly 8, not less (means: 1234567 is bad, but 12345678 is good)

Testcases:

- **Bad:**  `%`,  (empty string), `23b`, `-1`, `7.5`, `%5a`, `1`, `1234567`
- **Good:** `12345678`, `23%`, `1%53%53`,  `%7`

Comment: What are the `[` and `]` for? Remove those and see if it works.

Comment: `[\d%]+` means: a digit or percent character, one or more times. If you put + in the square brackets, it'll be interpreted as a literal `+`. The meaning of + (outside square brackets) is: the previous thing, one or more times.

Comment: Can you add some testcases to your question?

Comment: @halex testcase: GOOD: "12345678"  "23%" "1%53%35"  BAD: "23%b" "23%_" and so on

Comment: `1` and `1234567` are bad, but `12345678` is good? Why?

Comment: that's the definition for the program.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have a String, where only numbers and none, one or more percentages are allowed so my regex would be: `[\d+%]`

Actually, that matches ONE character which may be a digit, a `+` or a `%`.

To match what you have described in words, you need something like this:

```
  [\d%]*\d[\d%]*
```

which matches a string containing at least one digit with optional percent signs.  Note that the `%` character is not a meta-character and hence doesn't need to be escaped in the regex.  It will match all of the following:

```
  0
  00
  %0
  0%0
  00%
  0%0%0
  0%%0
```

and so on, but not just `%` or any string that contains characters other than digits or `%` characterss.

---

> Is there any good online tool for escaping a long regular expression for java?

I'm not aware of one.  But escaping wasn't the reason your regex wasn't working.

---

> A more advanced question: the % should be only allowed if a minimum of one digit is in the String, only a % shouldn't be allowed!

I think my regex above does that.  And for the record, here is what it looks like as a Java String literal:

```
"[\\d%]*\\d[\\d%]*"
```

Unless you have TAB, NL, CR, etc characters in the regex , it is sufficient to just replace each individual `\` with `\\`.

Comment: Stephen, great work...  i really have to get more and more into regex!

Comment: @Joerg - ummm ... my opinion on regexes is that they are over-rated and over-used.  Knowing how to use them is good, but using them as the default solution to any parsing problem is bad, IMO.

Comment: ok, i saw after the edit from somebody the testcase was not exact what i wanted... i updated my testcase, so maybe you know how to solve it?